# How to select all values in case of default in drop-down menu in sqlite3 query where clause

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to display a data in QTableWidget according to QComboBoxes. In case of select all gender or select all ages, I want apply select all in the column in sqlite3 query

## I want gender to be all

```
gender = "select all both male and female"
connection.execute("SELECT * FROM child where region=? and hospital=? and ageInMonths=? and gender=?", (region,hospital,ageInMonths,gender))
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

While it's a little tedious, the most sensible way to attack this problem is to build a list of the conditions you want to apply, and another of the data values that need to be inserted. Something like the following (untested) code, in which I assume that the variables are set to `None` if they aren't required in the search.

```
conditions = []
values = []
if region is not None:
    conditions.append('region=?')
    values.append(region)
 # And similar logic for each other value ...
if gender is not None:
    conditions.append('gender=?')
    values.append(gender)

query = 'SELECT * FROM child'
if conditions:
    query = query + ' WHERE ' + ' AND '.join(conditions)

connection.execute(query, values)
```

This way, if you want to include all values of a column you simply exclude if from the conditions by setting it to `None`.

Comment: I thought about this, but there will be a lot more conditions because because I have 7 drop-down menus, each of them indicate some filters, Is there any way to say select all in the where clause itself, And thank you for you time

Comment: Well, you could use something like `WHERE gender in (SELECT DISTINCT gender FROM child)`, but what would be the point? You're going to end up with horrible SQL that way ...

Answer (score 0):

You can build your where clause and your parameter list conditionally.

Below I am assuming that the `ageInMonths` and `gender` variables actually contain the value 'all' when this is selected on your form. You can change this to whichever value is actually passed to your code, if it is something different.

When it comes to your actual query, the best way to get all values for a field is to simply exclude it from the `where` clause of your query entirely.

So something like:

```
query_parameters = []
query_string = "SELECT * FROM child where region=? and hospital=?"
query_parameters.append(region)
query_parameters.append(hospital)
if ageInMonths != 'all':
    query_string += " and ageInMonths=?"
    query_parameters.append(ageInMonths)
if gender != 'all':
    query_string += " and gender=?"
    query_parameters.append(gender)
connection.execute(query_string, query_parameters)
```

Basically, at the same time we are testing and building the dynamic parts of the SQL statement (in `query_string`), we are also dynamically defining the list of variables to pass to the query in `query_parameters`, which is a `list` object.